# Angular i18m xliffmerge overwrites translations

Tags: angular, internationalization

My trans unit looks like this:

```
<trans-unit id="afd1971b15e59ed7edc553893ed4894124f58d4f" datatype="html">
        <source>{VAR_SELECT, select, action {action} other {
          <x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{actionMessages[0].action}}"/> } }
        </source>
        <target state="final">{VAR_SELECT, select, action {action} other {
          <x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{actionMessages[0].action}}"/> } }
        </target>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">app/devices/list/custom/simplepack/simplepack.component.ts</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">12</context>
        </context-group>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">app/devices/list/custom/simpleleak/simpleleak.component.ts</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">12</context>
        </context-group>
        <note priority="1" from="description">Last action</note>
        <note priority="1" from="meaning">Simple Pack</note>
      </trans-unit>
```

If I translate target part and add translations for action {action} like this:

```
<target state="final">{VAR_SELECT, select, {Short press} double_press {Double press} long_press {Long press} other {
     <x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{actionMessages[0].action}}"/> } }
</target>
```

The next extract with xliffmerge reset my translation back to the source. I have found that if I do not have other {...} part in the source, it works as expected. It also only happens with default English language. Other language files are fine. I do not want to keep all possible actions in the code and also need { other } part to display untranslated strings.

It is extremely annoying, because I have to fix it with every translation. Any idea?

Comment: is this ?: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#set-a-custom-id-for-persistence-and-maintenance

Comment: @Eliseo If I add custom ID, it creates a custom ID in original xlf file but then it is lost during xliffmerge, so there is no custom ID in final English xlf file. It looks like the issue is in xliffmerge. But without it I would need to translate the files over and over again..